# how can I know encoding scheme before opening a file?

Tags: java, encoding

JAVA,
When I try to open and read a file with BufferedReader, I'd received an error message that I used wrong encoding. So system invoked an exception that my encoder can not read the file. 
In this case, how i can know which kind of encoding is used to the file.
Of cause, if the file is written with "utf-8", then it's impossible to read the file with "euc-kr" encoding. My question is I'd like to get the Charset information before opening the file so that I can select right encoding scheme for that file. Anybody help me?

here is my code

```
package lecture06;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindExample01 {

    /**
     * Initialized in : getInput()
     * Used at : findPattern()
     */
    private static String pattern;

    /**
     * Initialized in initApplication
     * @param args
     */
    private static BufferedWriter wBuffer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initApplication();
        Path dir = Paths.get(getInput());
        System.out.println("root = " + dir.toString());
        System.out.println("pattern = " + pattern);
        searchDirectory(dir.toString());
        try {
            wBuffer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wBuffer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void initApplication()
    {
        try {
            wBuffer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("Index.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getInput()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dir = null;
        for(;;)
        {
            System.out.println("Root Directory: ");
            dir = sc.next();
            if (Files.exists(Paths.get(dir), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) break;
        }
        for(;;)
        {
            System.out.println("Find what ?");
            pattern = sc.next();
            if (pattern.length() > 2) 
            {
                sc.close();
                return dir;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void searchDirectory(String root)
    {
        File fiRoot = new File(root);
        File[] files = fiRoot.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory()) searchDirectory(file.getAbsolutePath());
            else findPattern(file.toPath());
        }
    }

    private static void findPattern(Path path)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader rBuffer = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            int count = 1;
            String line;
            while ((line = rBuffer.readLine()) != null)
            {
                int idx;
                while ((idx = line.indexOf(pattern)) != -1)
                    writeIndex(path.toString(), count, idx);
                count++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeIndex(String path, int count, int idx)
    {
        try {
            wBuffer.write(path + " : " + count + " : " + idx + " : " + pattern);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wBuffer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the source of your files?  Is there any chance you can find out the encoding before it even hits your Java code?

Comment: I'd like to implement a function named find() which shows files containing the pattern i'd like to search. So, I open all files from the root directory and if a file is found, I open the file and read all line to find the pattern. But my program can not open a file because of wrong encoding

Answer (score 2):

Try [juniversalchardet](https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet), it's an encoding detector library. It has a list of popular encodings that can be detected. For this you don't need to read the whole file, just the first bytes

```
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);
    int nread;
    while ((nread = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
        detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
    }
    detector.dataEnd();
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
```

Comment: Nice library, I guess https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet receives updates to the code while the Google code archive does not

Comment: So, I have to use 3'rd party solution to detect encoding. Java does not support automatic detecting functions which can distinguish encoding.